# how to compile and run on different Linux (Debian) versions

Tags: debian, compiling, libraries

Compiled on debian 10 with gcc 8.3 :

```
root@debian:/home/mongo# ldd /home/mongo/build/opt/mongo/db/mongod
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe9f1c0000)
        libcurl.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f1d7012d000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f1d70105000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f1d700eb0               
...
```

So I am sure it's compiled and linked as dynamically linked. it's actually using gcc 6 runtime .so from ldd although compiled with gcc 8:

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc6183c1000)  
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc618042000)
```

The same executable on Debian 9 which has gcc 6.3 :

```
ldd /usr/bin/mongod
        statically linked
```

and it segfaults

```
mongod[12662]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f25798fa821 sp 00007ffccda20090 error 4 in ld-2.24.so
```

What is this due to? How to compile and run on different Linux Debian versions ?

Comment: It is difficult to tell what you're trying to accomplish. One executable seems to be statically linked, the other dynamically linked. What is exactly you need it to do?

Comment: You say nothing about how you compiled the binary, assuming you have compiled it yourself. Have you tried installing MongoDB from packages via `apt`?

Comment: can you run something compiled with gcc 8 on linux which has gcc 6 in it's default distribution ?

Comment: # file /usr/bin/mongod.new
/usr/bin/mongod.new: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, missing section headers  
running "strip" on the executable seems to have removed "section headers"

Comment: root@MGFRW01 /storage # ldd mongod  
./mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by ./mongod)  
./mongod: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by ./mongod)  
./mongod: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by ./mongod)  
./mongod: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by ./mongod)